# How do I use triangular meshes on a dynamic object?

Tags: game-physics, physx

Can't I use triangular meshes on a dynamic body? I want a body whose shape is described by a triangular mesh to be able to work as dynamic, not as kinematic or static, so that it flies away from impacts and obeys the force of gravity.

What should I do to use triangular meshes on a dynamic object?

Answer (score 0):

Triangle mesh on triangle mesh collision is expensive computationally. So it is better to use a convex mesh for dynamic objects.